# mysqlで下位五件を上位から取得したいです

Tags: mysql

タイトルのとおりでございます

```
select * from column order by created desc limit 5;
```

のようにしたらもちろん降順に表示されるので

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

のようになります。

これを

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

にしたいです。

可能であればどのようなSQL文になるのか、具体的なコードも添えてくれると嬉しいです。

Comment: `(select * from column order by created desc limit 5) order by created asc;` ではどうですか。

Comment: ありがとうございます
なるほどです
降順にしてから昇順にするというわけですね
サブクエリかな？調べてみます！

Comment: コードは正常に実行できました！

Answer (score 1):

(コメントより)

```
(select * from column order by created desc limit 5) order by created asc;
```

ではどうですか。